# JQuery add/remove class for Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a navigation bar menu. The website default is on the About page. But what I'm trying to accomplish is that when I click on another menu item, like Experience, I'd like the About paragraph to change into the paragraph I have for Experience. I feel like this is very simple but I can't seem to get it right.

Thanks for your help! This is how my html looks:

```
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="title">
  <p><span style="font-size:55px;">—</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Jennifer</p>
</div>

<div class="jenpic">
  <img src="jen_1.svg" alt="" />
  <div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
</div>


<div id="text">
  <div class="bio">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>

  <div class="experience" style="display:none">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>

  <div class="education" style="display:none">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>

  <div class="contact" style="display:none">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your javascript? What isn't working right with it?

Comment: I just can't figure out what's the best way to approach this. As you can see, I set all of the paragraphs to display:none except the default About page. Is that correct? I wasn't sure then if I would target nav-bar li a onClick and remove the class for About and add the Experience class.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly simple. Here is a working snippet:

```js
$("#about").click(function() {
    $(".experience").hide();
  $(".education").hide();
  $(".contact").hide();
  $(".bio").show();
  });

$("#exp").click(function() {
    $(".bio").hide();
  $(".education").hide();
  $(".contact").hide();
  $(".experience").show();
  });

$("#edc").click(function() {
  $(".bio").hide();
  $(".experience").hide();
  $(".contact").hide();
  $(".education").show();
  });

$("#con").click(function() {
    $(".bio").hide();
  $(".education").hide();
  $(".experience").hide();
  $(".contact").show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li id="about"><a href="#about" >About Me</a></li>
    <li id="exp"><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li id="edc"><a href="#education" >Education</a></li>
    <li id="con"><a href="#contact" >Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="title">
  <p><span style="font-size:55px;">—</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Jennifer</p>
</div>

<div class="jenpic">
  <img src="jen_1.svg" alt="" />
  <div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
</div>


<div id="text">
  <div class="bio">
    <p>Hi, I’m Jennifer! I am a Speech-Language
      Pathologist providing private speech and
      language services to the pediatric population.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="experience" style="display:none">
    <p>Prompt I & II trained. Experienced in evaluating, diagnosing and treating speech sound disorders (including articulation, dysarthria, apraxia of speech, phonological), fluency disorders (stuttering), language delays/disorders and pragmatic (social) language weaknesses. Experienced in implementing and training AAC (augmentative and alternative communication) for nonverbal/emerging communicators. Skilled in working with ASD (Autism Spectrum Disorders) & a variety of developmental/medical conditions.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="education" style="display:none">
    <p>Hi, I’m Jennifer! I am a Speech-Language
      Pathologist providing private speech and
      language services to the pediatric population.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="contact" style="display:none">
    <p>Hi, I’m Jennifer! I am a Speech-Language
      Pathologist providing private speech and
      language services to the pediatric population.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever a menu button is clicked, it hides all the rest and shows the one that is clicked. I hope this helps!

Matt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @Jessica No problem! Please upvote and mark as correct answer if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery like this, there's no need of "display:none;":

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".experience").hide();
    $(".education").hide();
    $(".contact").hide();

$("#eduNavItem").click(function() {
    $(".bio").hide();
    $(".education").show();
});

});
```

#eduNavItem would be the id of the education item at the navigation bar.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry, could you be more specific? I'd be glad to correct my answer, but I read the How to answer page and I still don't understand what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the OP apparently doesn't know how jQuery works, or they'd have does this same thing already. Adding an explanation of how your code works would make it more useful to future readers. From that page: *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.*

Comment: @sebasaenz thank you it works perfectly! I did this:

$('ul li:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
        $('.bio').hide();
        $('.education').hide();
        $('.contact').hide();
        $('.experience').show();
    });

So when you click on each one, it hides anything that was there before.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make it so you could add more links and areas quickly.
Add a class to each section so you can hide them all at once.

Then use the href to find the correct section to show. (i have changed your "bio" div to about to match the href.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $sections = $('.js-section');
  $('#nav-bar a').on('click', function() {
     var ref = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
     $sections.hide();
     $("." + ref).show();
  });
});
```

Html

```
<nav id="nav-bar">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="title">
    <p><span style="font-size:55px;">—</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;name of person</p>
</div>

<div class="jenpic">
    <img src="blah.svg" alt="" />
    <div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div id="text">
    <div class="about js-section">
        <p>blah blah about</p>
    </div>
    <div class="experience js-section" style="display:none">
        <p>blah blah experience</p>
    </div>
    <div class="education js-section" style="display:none">
        <p>blah blah education</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact js-section" style="display:none">
        <p>blah blah contact</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to be similar to below. The advantage with this is that you can continue to develop your site and the code would never need to be changed. It works by using the data-target element to target the element that contains the text. Hope that is helpful ask any questions that you might have, I am happy to help!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('nav#nav-bar a').on('click',function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $( $( this ).attr('data-target') ).addClass('active');
 })

})
```

```css
#text > div {
 display:none;
}

.active {
 display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about" data-target="#bio">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#experience" data-target="#experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#education" data-target="#education">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" data-target="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="title">
  <p><span style="font-size:55px;">—</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Jennifer</p>
</div>

<div class="jenpic">
  <img src="jen_1.svg" alt="" />
  <div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
</div>


<div id="text">
  <div id='bio' class="active">
    <p>Hi, I’m Jennifer! I am a Speech-Language
      Pathologist providing private speech and
      language services to the pediatric population.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="experience">
    <p>Prompt I & II trained. Experienced in evaluating, diagnosing and treating speech sound disorders (including articulation, dysarthria, apraxia of speech, phonological), fluency disorders (stuttering), language delays/disorders and pragmatic (social) language weaknesses. Experienced in implementing and training AAC (augmentative and alternative communication) for nonverbal/emerging communicators. Skilled in working with ASD (Autism Spectrum Disorders) & a variety of developmental/medical conditions.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="education">
    <p>Hi, I’m Jennifer! I am a Speech-Language
      Pathologist providing private speech and
      language services to the pediatric population.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="contact">
    <p>Hi, I’m Jennifer! I am a Speech-Language
      Pathologist providing private speech and
      language services to the pediatric population.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```